# Пунктуационное оформление предложения

Tags: пунктуация

— Где ты был вчера ночью?
— Я уже говорил — на работе.
Какой знак следует поставить в предложении "Я уже говорил — на работе"?
В моем понимании, тут пропущен союз *что* и сказуемое *был*, поэтому я бы поставил здесь тире. Правильно ли это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что поставить? У нас всего-то три знака. Запятая точно не подходит, остается **тире или двоеточие.**

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП). По правилам Розенталя  **при изъяснительном значении** возможны оба знака, вот и примеры из  правил это подтверждают: *Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала* (Кр.);  **Я говорю: не сдамся** (Л. Т.).

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150

https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Итак, у нас два варианта ответа: (1) *Я уже говорил –  на работе.* (2) *Я уже говорил: на работе.*

С одной стороны,  ваш вариант больше похож  на пример из Розенталя  **с тире** – там тоже **повтор сказанного,** а двоеточием обозначается обычное оформление дословного высказывания, как при прямой речи.

С другой стороны, здесь есть возможность с помощью знака обозначить **тональность фразы**. При постановке двоеточия вы говорите неторопливо, делаете **предупредительную паузу**. А при постановке присоединительного тире ответ **краткий**, почти без паузы.